# Destruir sessões em PHP

Tags: php, session

Estava pesquisando sobre funções de *logout* em php e ví uns exemplos do tipo:

```
if(isset($_SESSION)) { 
     unset($_SESSION['minhaSessao']); //repetir para cada sessao
     session_unregister(); 
     session_destroy(); 
}
```

Queria saber se não há algum modo de limpar todas as sessões ativas da minha aplicação sem precisar setar uma por uma repetidamente.

Comment: O que são "todas as sessões"? Todos os dados de sessão de um usuário, ou de todos os usuários? Se for o último caso, as respostas atuais não te servem.

Comment: @bfavaretto as respostas serviram sim, agradeço a preocupação. São as sessões do usuário em questão, como eu disse na pergunta, seria para uma função de *logout*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Este código está redundante, apenas `session_destroy();` isoladamente já resolve o caso. Não precisa do `if` , nem dos demais comandos.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php

Comment: Para complementar, usando um arquivo logout.php.

e neste aquivo coloca essa função de `session_destray()` e outra de `header()` já resolve a sua necessidade.

Comment: Valeu, seviu pro meu caso! Mas notei que se fizer o teste e tentar escrever a `session` logo após o `session_destroy();` ela ainda continua com o valor, e só depois de redirecionar a página que aí sim os valores somem.

Comment: @DirtyOldMan, este é o comportamento esperado. Apenas no próximo carregamento da página que perderá o acesso. Estou editando a resposta para ficar mais claro.

Answer (score 1):

crie um arquivo apenas com `session_destroy();` e use como logoff, já é o suficiente para quebrar todas as sessões do php

Comment: ok, não tinha lido este tópico anteriormente!